# How to restore deleted OOB Timer Job

Tags: timer-jobs

One of development server "delete job history" job got deleted accidently. Now how to restore it back? We have ran the configuration wizard, but no luck.

Comment: is the job definition still there?

Comment: no job definition is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I configured stored procedure to run from SQL. The stored procedure name is [proc_DeleteOldTimerJobHistory] which is available in SharePoint_config database.

**New Update:**

I got another solution to resolve issue.

Running below `Powershell` scripts restore the deleted default timer Job.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm  
$farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

Reference: [How to Restore sharepoint out of box deleted timer jobs](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Restore-sharepoint-e2bb6d06#content)

Answer (score 4):

If the timer job is gone, the only way (apart from re-installing the entire farm) to get the deleted timer job back is to run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard which will re-install the missing timer job.

Reference: [Restoring the Out of the Box Timer Jobs](http://wscheema.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=17)

Comment: We ran the  SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard and gave the restart to the server but no luck.

Comment: @ps Strange. Looks like the only way to get it back is through a custom solution or a complete re-install and content move.

Comment: Thanks Benny. I will not go for complete re-install as i am a SharePoint developer doing admin job as there is no admin.  Can you give me idea how to do it with custom solution? I googled a bit and found that "Delete job history" uses a store procedure to delete history data from sharepoint config database. Is i have to run that store procedure from custom solution?

Comment: Also is i am allow to run that store procedure from config database. As Microsoft says don't touch there database.

Comment: @ps Microsoft says you can't alter database content, but to configure a procedure to run from SQL I guess wouldn't compromise warrenty. I guess thats the fastest solution for your problem, even if I'd do a complete package to replace the missing timer job. See [Create and Deploy Custom Timer Job Definition in SharePoint Programatically](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S)

Comment: Hi Benny, I got another solution also. We have to just run few powershell commands. I updated my answer.